# Simulation (monte carlo? Python)

Tags: python, loops, simulation, montecarlo, maximize

I would like to know to use which technique to find out the best parameters in my problem in. Is Monte Carlo what I should look after?

My problem:

I want to test several parameters in a model (**Non-linear in reality**) that can maximize an indicator.

Simple example (in)

```
l1=[1,2,3,4,5]
l2=[5,6,7,8]
1<=x1<=2
1<=x2<=2

m=np.min(l1) * x1 - np.min(l2) * x2
```

I want to find the value of `x1, x2` that can maximize `m`, **not using mathematics**, but by trying numbers between 1 and 2 on a step of 0.1. (The answer obviously is `x1: 2, x2: 1`)

Firstly, how can I write the code?

Secondly, is this a Monte Carlo simulation problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Read the tag description of monte-carlo. It uses random-samples. Not much randomness in your task! Your task is just a grid-search and is simple (nested) looping.

Comment: @sascha I am wondering is that random sample x1, x2? and find the maximum result?

Comment: As long as you do not import random or implement your own PRNG (or somehow add external entropy/randomness), there is no randomness.

Comment: I believe you need to think about your problem a bit more, to clarify what exactly you want to do.